# unit vector in recession cone

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, convex-cone

The [recession cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recession_cone) of $\Omega$. If $d_u$ is a unit vector, show that $d_u\in R(\Omega)$ iff there exists unbounded sequence $\{ w^k \}_{k=1}^\infty\subset \Omega$ satisfying
$$\frac{w^k}{\|w^k\|}\to d_u\quad as\;k\to\infty$$

I don't know where to start the proof. I've tried from the definition but failed. Maybe there needs some construction?

Please give me some hints. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are missing the assumption that $\Omega$ is convex. One direction is immediate and follows directly from the definition...